# How do I assign an Interior-Object to a Range?

Tags: vba

I have created an Interior variable in vba to store the style of a certain cell. Excel lets me do it but when I try to apply that style to any other cell it does not work.

```
Sub JustTest()
    Dim X As Interior
    Set X = Range("H12").Interior   'stores the Interior values into X

    X.TintAndShade = -0.05          'could alter the values if needed to

    Set Range("H15").Interior = X   'this line does not work

End Sub
```

I was expecting that I could "copy" a style from (in this example) Range H12 to Range H15 but I get a runtime error 438.
Doing it this way I could alter the Interior values at runtime.
I guess it's simple but I am a blockhead. Anyone an idea? Thanks in advance!

Comment: You are storing a reference to that cell's interior into `X`. Then you change that cell's interior via the reference stored in `X`. You cannot create a new instance of Interior, and thus you cannot assign one cell's interior to another cell. You can only assign properties of one Interior to be equal to properties of another Interior, one by one.

Comment: Yes, @GSerg is right `.Interior` property is ReadOnly...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a `sub method` to set all the (non-object) properties of `Interior` object, thus achieving what you want.

Instead of your `set Range("H15").Interior = X` statement you would use:

`Call setInterior(Range("H15"),X)`.

```
    Sub setInterior(rRange As Range, interiorStyle As Interior)
        Dim interiorTarget As Interior
        
        Set interiorTarget = rRange.Interior
        
        On Error Resume Next
        
        With interiorTarget 
    '        .Application
            .Color = interiorStyle.Color
            .ColorIndex = interiorStyle.ColorIndex
    '        .Creator
    '        .Gradient
             .InvertIfNegative = interiorStyle.InvertIfNegative
    '        .Parent
            .Pattern = interiorStyle.Pattern
            .PatternColor = interiorStyle.PatternColor
            .PatternColorIndex = interiorStyle.PatternColorIndex
            .PatternThemeColor = interiorStyle.PatternThemeColor
            .PatternTintAndShade = interiorStyle.PatternTintAndShade
            .ThemeColor = interiorStyle.ThemeColor
            .TintAndShade = interiorStyle.TintAndShade
        End With
    
    End Sub
```

Object/Read-only properties are commented but shown for completeness. `InvertIfNegative` seems to sometimes have an error, thus the `On Error Resume Next` statement to avoid problems with it.

Comment: Your both interiors are called `rgInt`.

Comment: Thx. Correction applied. Never use find&replace after testing to make your code more legible....... :-)

Comment: Thanks! I thought there would be a built-in vba function or so but that works fine! ;)